# How to filter http request URL by mime type?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to make a shell script which filters http request URL by mime type. (ex: image/jpg image)

I used tcpdump to sniff packets and grep to filter http headers.
This is my current command:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S tcpdump -vvAtp -i en5 tcp port 80 | grep -E GET\|Content-Type:.*image.*
```

This filters http URL and content-type header.
I want some improvement, but I can't figure out how to do these:

- Prints URL when only Content-Type is image.
- There is no newline character before GET, so dirty characters prefixed before GET. I wanna remove those characters. Including "GET" or "HTTP 1.1" itself if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for (which would require some sed/awk/perl fanciness), but I think you'll like this:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S tcpdump -vvAtp -i en5 tcp port 80 | grep -oE 'GET.*|Content-Type:.*image.*'
```

Well, here's a first try.  Completely untested:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S tcpdump -vvAtp -i en5 tcp port 80 | grep -oE 'GET|Content-Type:.*image.*' | perl -npe 's/\n/#####/ if /GET/;' | grep -oE '#####[^#][^#]*$'
```

Comment: Thanks. I got a hint this requires some kind of programming. I'll dig it later.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is enough of a departure to warrant another answer, especially since, this time, I could actually test it before posting it.

Here's my test string generator:

```
TESTSTRING='GET /foo/bar\nX-Random-Header: true\nContent-Type: text/html\nGET /foo/baz.jpg\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\nGET /index.html\nContent-Type: text/html\nGET /one/two.png\nContent-Type: image/png\nX-Another-Random-Header: 42\nGET /some.gif\nContent-Type: image/gif'
/bin/echo -e $TESTSTRING
```

It produces the following output:

```
GET /foo/bar
X-Random-Header: true
Content-Type: text/html
GET /foo/baz.jpg
Content-Type: image/jpeg
GET /index.html
Content-Type: text/html
GET /one/two.png
Content-Type: image/png
X-Another-Random-Header: 42
GET /some.gif
Content-Type: image/gif
```

Now here's the evolution of the output:

---

**First step: Filter out lines that don't contain GET or Content-Type, and while we're at it, use the "-o" flag to filter out any strangeness at the start of those lines.**

```
/bin/echo -e $TESTSTRING | \
 grep -oE 'GET.*|Content-Type:.*image.*'
```

Produces:

```
GET /foo/bar
GET /foo/baz.jpg
Content-Type: image/jpeg
GET /index.html
GET /one/two.png
Content-Type: image/png
GET /some.gif
Content-Type: image/gif
```

---

**Step two: Remove newlines from all GET lines.  This will "stack up" the GETs.  Since the only lines that aren't "GETs" are the Content-Type lines, this means that we end up with one Content-Type per line.**

```
/bin/echo -e $TESTSTRING | \
 grep -oE 'GET.*|Content-Type:.*image.*' | \
 perl -npe 's/\n/#####/ if /GET/;'
```

Produces:

```
GET /foo/bar#####GET /foo/baz.jpg#####Content-Type: image/jpeg
GET /index.html#####GET /one/two.png#####Content-Type: image/png
GET /some.gif#####Content-Type: image/gif
```

---

**Step three: Get rid of everything except that last GET/Content-Type pair.**

```
/bin/echo -e $TESTSTRING | \
 grep -oE 'GET.*|Content-Type:.*image.*' | \
 perl -npe 's/\n/#####/ if /GET/;' | \
 grep -oE '[^#]*#####[^#][^#]*$'
```

Produces:

```
GET /foo/baz.jpg#####Content-Type: image/jpeg
GET /one/two.png#####Content-Type: image/png
GET /some.gif#####Content-Type: image/gif
```

---

**Step four: We can now strip off the Content-Type.**

```
/bin/echo -e $TESTSTRING | \
 grep -oE 'GET.*|Content-Type:.*image.*' | \
 perl -npe 's/\n/#####/ if /GET/;' | \
 grep -oE '[^#]*#####[^#][^#]*$' | \
 sed 's/#####.*//; s/GET //;'
```

Produces:

```
/foo/baz.jpg
/one/two.png
/some.gif
```

Which, as I understand it, is your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/), it brings the raw power of the grep to the network traffic. Here are some [examples how to use it](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/usage.html).